# very simple WebForm with masterpage

Tags: asp.net, webforms, http-get

I use method=get to send my data from one webform to the other. But I don't want to have in the URL query things like:

> `Search.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKLTYwODIwNTg5MQ9kFgJmD2QWAgIDDxYCHgZtZXRob2QFA2dldGRkGOirvzjoAxt%2BfOb915%2FpsYZXmAxLZZdpnK6UW7A9%2Fk83D&__PREVIOUSPAGE=cog5Yzt_1GerH9r2ERTIPbLWMCwMFYteZjmDYCbBO3vobCG4C_mWM7GZMNuBesyAjw77cvuNKl_aSUYzeajiW6W0CjI0tLB6ikjcM4t5Kbg1&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWAgKYsPjPDQKY24%2FQBBH4CPejKl3spy0A%2BtpMxb%2BCGVGJf73dYtmaEnIFF4IR&name=Amy&state=24&ctl00%24MainContent%24submit=Searchbut`

I only want the name and the state to be in the Get query like:

> ?name=Amy&state=24

```
<configuration>
```

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>



</system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: how are you setting the session in your web.config?

Comment: I'm not setting it at all. In edit I list my full webconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the additional parameters appear to be view state ones?

You could consider turning off view state – see this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972427.aspx) which would get you closer to your desired URL.

Other options include switching to POST as the method or using some other mechanism to pass the additional data such as setting cookies.

Or moving to something like ASP.Net MVC which would allow your more control over how URLs are created/used.